# Similarity metric for 3D histograms

Tags: image-processing, histogram, data-mining, similarity, opencv, python

I want to cluster images based on colour similarity. For that I need a good similarity metric between two 3D histograms. A 3D histogram of an image is just a 3 dimensional space where each axis represents one of the base colours. The range of each axis is 0-255 since this are the possible values of the base colours for each pixel.

The histogram is represented as a 256X256X256 matrix and each entry in the matrix represents the count of pixels with that specific colour in the image. For example:
If the value of the matrix element `M[0][0][0] = 1150` it means that there are 1150 black pixels in the image (RGB(0,0,0) represents the colour black)

I am looking for the most sensible similarity metric for this kind of problem. The metric will be used in the clustering algorithm (DBSCAN probably) to evaluate image similarity.

Comment: Calculate the euclidean distance between the each point of the first and second histogram?

Comment: But it seems to me that euclidean distance is not the best choice since it is perceptually important how a colour differs from one example to the other. For example if you have a white image with RGB(255,255,255) and you compare it to an image with RGB(170,170,170) => light grey and image with RGB(255,0,255) => purple  . It is clear that white is more similar to light grey than purple. I would like to capture the uniform change among the RGB values in my similarity metric.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `L*a*b*` (CIELAB) color space, where euclidean distance is indeed similarity, as it is designed to model human eye perceptions non-linearities.